# Typescript: Trying to setup a dynamic keyof typing

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to setup a typing where I want a specific type to be resolved from an object property:

```js
interface SubjectA {
    id: string
    title: string
    description: string | null
    quantity: number
    links: string[]
}

let subjectA: SubjectA = {
    id: "abc",
    title: "def",
    description: null,
    quantity: 45,
    links: ["ghi", "jkl"],
}

executeProcessor(subjectA, {
    processors: [
        {
            id: "title",
            process: (should_be_infered_as_string) => {},
        },
        {
            id: "description",
            process: (should_be_infered_as_string_or_null) => {},
        },
        {
            id: "quantity",
            process: (should_be_infered_as_number) => {},
        },
        {
            id: "links",
            process: (should_be_infered_as_string_list) => {},
        },
    ],
})
```

Here, I'd like my parameter of `process` callback to be infered as the type of the property that match the given `id`.

Making the interface for the processor's item is not difficult:

```js
interface PropertyProcessor<T, K extends keyof T> {
    id: K,
    process: (value: T[K]) => void
}
```

However, I'm struggling with typing the `processors` attribute itself:

```js
interface ItemProcessor<T> {
    processors: PropertyProcessor<T, what_to_put_here_?>[]
}
```

So far, I've used `keyof T` as a replacement of `what_to_put_here_?`. But my parameters are now infered as any of the possible options (`string | null | number | string[]`).

I think my `PropertyProcessor` type should not have a generics `K`, and should determine itself the type of the `process` parameter:

```js
interface PropertyProcessor<T> {
    id: keyof T,
    process: (value: T[same_as_id_type]) => void
}
```

But I don't known how to do this.

Thanks in advance for you're help.

[Playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQPYAdpgJ7oZIDOxGUAPACoA0yA0shAB6QgAmxyA1hHhjGRUAfMgDeAKGTTkwdgC4GNKTKyYSxRQAoAbnAA2AVwiKqAbXoBdAJTIAvKJ0Y5EgL4SJoSLEQoAkpAAtoQa5NSikjLIakQQpOSaaJg4UPghcWSUtDx8AkLCZpZuHjCGIAhgwBggTMwQCIaQ6fFZwlrAQaZ0MaFQigEQweoZYSK2kTIA9JPIcCB4YAAWoADmyIvQEMUS08gAosxwgVj6KHmGxHArW57g0PBIyADKhgBGAFb1YACC4irSckUxDAUFW-2QlTApyBILBUXYcQQoKwlWqMNBIDWAB9kCBDPp9OCAI6GOaQvCKPGBV7QcH6UDcRLAjErQrbU5gZDEN6fCrfRQvD5fX52P5RQHIABEcFeCElyiikOhUoRMHl4IRxCRwBRVRAlPx+gVMhJZI6FOQABYAKzG6T0kCMxRmSUrZbyqXvbj6SWWZTuCQseqNCDNTJablCvl0CbSHojKCJMzgqKxqLpiWSpUQdXpvPRYakbTERYYfHsAD6NIroBgm0rcGIFeZq1sDnErjt6c7KZkafzsgUKsRyNRIFzA9UhcSEdL5arEBrIDrUAgDabLcxFfIFbxBLbER7A6P+f7+czpvA5onk4LsSLyFnZf0lertfrFcbu8M1OgB47XZRCeeZnnmmYOoyN6TvGD5PvOb7Lh+X6bisFb0sC-5iMB3Zdn6bjWBIQA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get typescript to do this by adding a type parameter that will be inferred as a tuple of keys, and then mapping that tuple using a mapped type back to the array of processors:

```
type ProcessorMap<T, K extends Array<keyof T>> = {
    [P in keyof K]: PropertyProcessor<T, K[P] & keyof T>
}

function executeProcessor<T,P extends [keyof T] | (keyof T)[]>(item: T, processor: {
    processors: ProcessorMap<T, P>
}) {
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQPYAdpgJ7oZIDOxGUAPACoA0yA0shAB6QgAmxyA1hHhjGRUAfMgDeAKGTTkwdgC4GNKTKyYSxRQAoAbnAA2AVwiKqAbXoBdAJTIAvKJ0Y5EgL4SJ+HGnURS5AFk4LGo6RhY2TmQAQSgoODwKXn5BEVE7cRVpM1RZEB4+AQZLRUIcKHxCDXJQhhzLZAAyApShYTcPGEMQBDBgDHyWCARDSCq-MkpaXIiIDi4zZKKqBoAfZC0l1OszS2EtYEgAW1M6NSIJ8kVJGWRz6qhNHwv-KCCQ2jR211tJdwlQJBYIgUABlQwAIwAVsMwNFMrc5IpiGAoKAAOZZZB9MD6EzIFFokCY27sPwINFYPoDZGojHIdYgQz6fRYgCOhjg4EOeEUTKOEOgWP0oG4T0JGN2HQkeLABMhMN60UU4OhsPhGRuMiRyAARHAIQhdcpbji8YpdWSYMasWTiBTgFT+iA+cz9CaZByuTjecgACwAVg90hFIDFijMuvRAAtgMa9VDuPpdZZlP8hiMxr5XlpiAr1XQtdJ7pdHhGsbci7dqzrdWaIDbq027tmnrnoxhmewAPqC7ugGDQCA9uDEbsS4m2BziZCuYPVucVmRV5uyBR6u0Op0DRur1St7TEDtd3sQfsgQdQYfd0fjunE7vkbtMllT0RiWfz26L1cr5u1r1uXwXc9xbF42yPTt9B7PsByHEcx35QUoDfGcf2bdCmz-Jta1DMUQL3EtSEPY9oNPc9L2vW8J3RbsRRRVCP0whd51TNxrAkIA)

The constraint `[keyof T] | (keyof T)[]` makes `P` be inferred to a tuple. Then we use the mapped type `ProcessorMap` to map back to the tuple we actually want.